# What does the short form represent for Korean Parts of Speech?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request, word-origin, abbreviated

Sometimes, I see these in dictionary word lists that has a short form for Korean Parts of Speech (POS) and I could figure out the "long-form", e.g.

- 감 = 감탄사   interjection, exclamation
- 관 = 관형사   determiner, pre-noun
- 대 = 대명사   pronoun
- 동 = 동사    verb
- 명 = 명사    noun
- 부 = 부사    adverb
- 수 = 수사    numeral, quantity indicator
- 형 = 형용사   adjective

(Please correct me if I'm wrong about the above)

But there're also these other short forms that are attached to their corresponding words:

- 보, e.g. 가지다, 계시다, 나가다, 내다, 놓다, 드리다
- 고, e.g. 독일, 러시아, 미국, 부산
- 불, e.g. 그래도, 그렇게, 얘, 어때
- 의, e.g. 개, 개월, 거, 것, 권

**What should does `보`, `고`, `불`, `의` mean? What's their "long form"?**

Purely from guessing, I think

- 고 ~= seems like geolocations?
- 불 ~= some sort of expression?
- 의 ~= some sort of counting?
- 보 ~= I'm clueless what `보` means...

Comment: One thing I'm at least partially sure about is '고': it looks like 고 stands for 고유명사(proper noun). 보 maybe stands for 보어 but I'm not really sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

고: 고유 명사 (proper noun), when the noun is a specific location or person.

보: 보조 동사(auxiliary verb), to be added after another verb/adjective to adjust the meaning.

Ex: 이기다 => 이겨내다

의: 의존 명사(dependent noun), namely nouns that must follow a specified grammatical pattern.

I can't find any info. on 불. If you tell me which dictionary you saw this, it will be more helpful.

Comment: I saw it from keytokorean =)

Comment: @alvas keytokorean is not a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

According to the website of the LA한국교육원 (http://kecla.org/board_TnIG78/1331), apparently based on data form the 국립국어원:

품사 약호

감 : 감탄사

고 : 고유 명사

관 : 관형사

대 : 대명사

동 : 동사

명 : 명사

보 : 보조 용언

부 : 부사

불 : 분석 불능

수 : 수사

의 : 의존 명사

형 : 형용사